# Is there a way to quickly add login/ sign up page with Google login and cookie verification to keep session live after revisiting the webapp in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I tried to google if there is an easier way to do authentication that reduces development efforts. I am sure there must be some solution. Help please.

Comment: Have you tried firebase? It's pretty easy to use with React.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I found out it is not scalable.